# What to do if you don't have Username

Tags: windows-xp, data-recovery

I've managed to load ubuntu onto an XP system that's died, but it asks for the username and password, I have my password but not the username...is there any other way to logon and use ubuntu to recover data?

Comment: Is it windows that is asking for the username? A bit confused as to the question you are asking. Sorry

Comment: Could you clarify your issue a bit more?  When booting Ubuntu from a ____(Live CD?), you're being asked for the username/password?

Comment: Yep when I run the try ubuntu option it loads and sets up ubuntu leaving a coloured background 4-5 small icon top right of screen and a logon box, which asks for a username and password, I'm guessing this is from my xp windows install

Answer (score 0):

You can boot from an Ubuntu LiveCD and access data on a Windows or Linux partitions on your hard disk - they should just appear in the left pane of the file manager.

This only won't work if a partition is encrypted or severely damaged.